# What is Abe's first name?

Tags: liar-game

When they first introduced her, they called her Yukiko Abe, but then the next few chapters that I read were translated by a different translator, and they translated her name to "Yukiyo Abe". However, [Wikia](http://liarsgame.wikia.com/wiki/Abe_Yukiko) says that the kanji for her name is 由紀子, which would be read as "Yukiko".

So which is it? Yukiyo or Yukiko?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Her full name is Yukiyo Abe.**

[Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIAR_GAME#%E7%AC%AC%E5%9B%9B%E5%9B%9E%E6%88%A6%E6%9C%AC%E6%88%A6) listed her name as

> アベ ユキヨ（黒髪ポニーテール）
>   Yukiyo Abe (Black Ponytail)

[MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/character/86065/Yukiyo_Abe) also confirms the name as

> Yukiyo "500 Year Old One" Abe

---

As for why the translator seemed to confuse "Yukiyo" with "Yukiko", コ (*ko*) and ヨ (*yo*) looks similar, having only 1 stroke difference. In addition of that, Yukiko is a more popular name in Japan than Yukiyo. Note however, her name is never written in kanji, thus there is no official kanji representation of her name.